# IIS "build" management

Tags: svn, iis, coldfusion

I have a client with a subsidiary doing web development using ColdFusion to support a government website.

We're having issues with devs not using source control.  I realize there's a whole bunch of political jazz associated with that that ought to be resolved, but I don't have a stake in that game.

Is there anything resembling a "build manager" for IIS?  That is to say, an app that will checkout code from SVN when told to, and deposit it in the appropriate directory of IIS?  Normally I'd trust the dev team to do it, but most of them don't seem to be even checking code into SVN, so I've been tasked with finding a technical workaround, if such is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use svnkit and have a batch file that can be setup as a scheduled task or linked into a webpage to run and  it checks out the code into the relevant directory.

http://svnkit.com/

Comment: So does the use of the batch file require SVNKit?  Because from my admittedly limited view of it, it appears to just be a pure Java implementation of SVN...

Comment: No svnkit has a command line client also. So you could hook it into a web app or do a batch file

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how to hook it into a web app?  I can do the batch file, but that only works if I do a scheduled task, and this method will only really work with on-demand code syncing.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can just use cfexecute to run the batch file